# How to browse message by ID

Tags: activemq-artemis

I need to browse a message by ID.

In `QueueControl.class` I find the method `browse()`, which return all messages, and method `browse(@Parameter(name = "filter", desc = "A message filter (can be empty)")`.

[image]

I tried to get the message with a filter `"messageID = '10737437509'"` (based on the example here https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html), but this didn't work.

How to browse the message by ID?

Comment: Filters work on message *properties* and some selected attributes (e.g. `AMQDurable`, `AMQPriority`, etc.). See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html) for more details on this. The message ID you're inspecting is not filterable. It's really meant for internal use and only displayed for informational or debugging purposes here.

Comment: The messageID maybe used for internal purposes only, but the messageID is used on various other methods on the [QueueControl interface](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html) (for example moving messages). It seems obvious that the browse method also supports messageID as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering seems to be applied to message properties only, not headers (like messageID).

You can set a custom message id property before send:

```java
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("abc");
message.setIntProperty("myMessageID", 123);
producer.send(message);
```

Then, you can filter by property like this:

```java
CompositeData[] browse = queueControl.browse("myMessageID=123");
if (browse != null && browse.length > 0) {
    System.out.println((String) browse[0].get("text"));
}
```

Comment: I already have messageID in the corresponding prop in the contents of CompositeData (attached screenshot in question). I think the identifier is set automatically by the broker

Comment: Filtering seems to be applied to message properties only, not headers (like messageID). Let me update the example, so it's more clear.